# How can I insert value to `@OrderBy` mapped columns automaticly in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have related entities: One `User` -> many `Orders`.

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = LAZY)
    private List<Order> orders;
```

I want to get ordered orders when I select the user and get all orders from it. I can create a new field in the orders table `ordinal_number` and add `@OrderBy` annotation:

```
@OrderBy("ordinal_number")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = LAZY)
private List<Order> orders;
```

But I don't understand how can I insert correct value to `ordinal_number` during save. I create user, create a list of orders, add a user to each order and add list orders to the user. And save the user. 
The primitive way -  create an int variable, add it manually to each order and increment.  But maybe there are some ways do it automatically? (for example, add some generator, autoincrement or something other)?

EDIT:

My order class:

```
EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "user")
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "insert_date")
    private Date insertDate = new Date();

    @Column(name = "ordinal_number")
    private Integer ordinalNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

My User class:

```
@ToString(exclude = "orders")
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OrderColumn(name = "ordinal_number")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = LAZY)
    private List<Order> orders;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`OrderBy` is used to *sort* the elements.

Suppose you have a `List<Person>`, and each person has a name, you would then want to have the persons sorted by name.

If several persons have the same name, then they will be next to each other in the list.

If you change the name of a person, then the next time you get that list, the person's position in the list will be changed, according to its new name.

What you want apparently is not that, but instead yo want to preserve the insertion order of orders in the list. I.e. have a `List<Order>` which always contains the first order, then the second, then the third. And if you add a 4th one, it should always be in 4th position.

That's what [`OrderColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) is for.

Comment: For example, I need to save 10 users. Each user has 5 orders. I want to save the first user with orders where each order has value in `ordinal_number` column  1 .2 3 4 5. And save the second user with orders 1 2 3 4 5 and etc. Ok, I will use  `OrderColumn` but my question - can I insert 1 2 3 45 values automatically to `ordinal_number`? or I need to add it manually?

Comment: Read the documentation. The second sentence is: *The persistence provider is responsible for maintaining the order upon retrieval and in the database. The persistence provider is responsible for updating the ordering upon flushing to the database to reflect any insertion, deletion, or reordering affecting the list.*. So, you add orders in the list, or modify the order of the list, and your persistence provider (hibernate) will maintain the order automatically.

Comment: I edit my question and add my entities. When I save `user` with `List<Order>` - `ordinal_number` column is NULL